# Data is not set when using v-mask in v-text-field in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using this library: https://github.com/probil/v-mask

The mask works only when the data is entered manually, but not when I set the data coming from the backend.

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="value" 
  v-mask="mask"/>  

<script>
   import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';
   
   export default {
            
        data: () => ({
            mask: createNumberMask({
                prefix: '',
                includeThousandsSeparator: true,
                thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '.',
                integerLimit: 8,
            }),
        }),

        created(){
            this.value = "1.345.678"
        }
     }

</script>
```

This problem has already been raised here: https://github.com/probil/v-mask/issues/500

I appreciate the help in advance.